# Incomplete Expression in R

Tags: r, vector

I'm currently running a time series script in R-Markdown where I pass the values of Percent Use and another vector of the time values. I am processing the two separate vectors with the regular c() function within r. The percentage vector is able to be passed through when compilining like normal, however I am running into trouble with the date/time vector. The length of both vectors are 749, the percentage vector just has values 0-100 passed within them. THe date/time vector has strings passed into them as such:

```
dt=c('2022-06-19 14:05:00.0','2022-06-19 14:06:00.0', ....
```

If I only pass a few arguments into the dt vector, it will compile regularly, however, once I increase the size to around half of what it needs to be I start getting the following error:

```
Error: Incomplete expression: dt=c('2022-06-19 12:40:00.0','2022-06-19 12:41:00.0','2022-06-19 12:42:00.0','2022-06-19 12:43:00.0','2022-06-19 12:44:00.0','2022-06-19 12:45:00.0','2022-06-19 12:46:00.0','2022-06-19 12:47:00.0','2022-06-19 12:48:00.0','2022-06-19 12:49:00.0','2022-06-19 12:50:00.0','2022-06-19 12:51:00.0','2022-06-19 12:52:00.0','2022-06-19 12:53:00.0','2022-06-19 12:54:00.0','2022-06-19 12:55:00.0','2022-06-19 12:56:00.0','2022-06-19 12:57:00.0','2022-06-19 12:58:00.0','2022-06-19 12:59:00.0','2022-06-19 13:00:00.0','2022-06-19 13:01:00.0','2022-06-19 13:02:00.0','2022-06-19 13:03:00.0','2022-06-19 13:04:00.0','2022-06-19 13:05:00.0','2022-06-19 13:06:00.0','2022-06-19 13:07:00.0','2022-06-19 13:08:00.0','2022-06-19 13:09:00.0','2022-06-19 13:10:00.0','2022-06-19 13:11:00.0','2022-06-19 13:12:00.0','2022-06-19 13:13:00.0','2022-06-19 13:14:00.0','2022-06-19 13:15:00.0','2022-06-19 13:16:00.0','2022-06-19 13:17:00.0','2022-06-19 13:18:00.0','2022-06-19 13:19:00.0','2022
```

At first I believed it could be a parenthesis in the wrong place, however, there is no mistakes with that. I've looked at other articles with somewhat similar issues and have seen a concept of a maximum size vector allowed, however the percentage vector was able to pass all 700. Is there a way to bypass this error, I feel that it is a memory/storage issue with R.
The full code is a lot but it is:

```
dt=c('2022-06-19 12:40:00.0','2022-06-19 12:41:00.0','2022-06-19 12:42:00.0','2022-06-19 12:43:00.0','2022-06-19 12:44:00.0','2022-06-19 12:45:00.0','2022-06-19 12:46:00.0','2022-06-19 12:47:00.0','2022-06-19 12:48:00.0','2022-06-19 12:49:00.0','2022-06-19 12:50:00.0','2022-06-19 12:51:00.0','2022-06-19 12:52:00.0','2022-06-19 12:53:00.0','2022-06-19 12:54:00.0','2022-06-19 12:55:00.0','2022-06-19 12:56:00.0','2022-06-19 12:57:00.0','2022-06-19 12:58:00.0','2022-06-19 12:59:00.0','2022-06-19 13:00:00.0','2022-06-19 13:01:00.0','2022-06-19 13:02:00.0','2022-06-19 13:03:00.0','2022-06-19 13:04:00.0','2022-06-19 13:05:00.0','2022-06-19 13:06:00.0','2022-06-19 13:07:00.0','2022-06-19 13:08:00.0','2022-06-19 13:09:00.0','2022-06-19 13:10:00.0','2022-06-19 13:11:00.0','2022-06-19 13:12:00.0','2022-06-19 13:13:00.0','2022-06-19 13:14:00.0','2022-06-19 13:15:00.0','2022-06-19 13:16:00.0','2022-06-19 13:17:00.0','2022-06-19 13:18:00.0','2022-06-19 13:19:00.0','2022-06-19 13:20:00.0','2022-06-19 13:21:00.0','2022-06-19 13:22:00.0','2022-06-19 13:23:00.0','2022-06-19 13:24:00.0','2022-06-19 13:25:00.0','2022-06-19 13:26:00.0','2022-06-19 13:27:00.0','2022-06-19 13:28:00.0','2022-06-19 13:29:00.0','2022-06-19 13:30:00.0','2022-06-19 13:31:00.0','2022-06-19 13:32:00.0','2022-06-19 13:33:00.0','2022-06-19 13:34:00.0','2022-06-19 13:35:00.0','2022-06-19 13:36:00.0','2022-06-19 13:37:00.0','2022-06-19 13:38:00.0','2022-06-19 13:39:00.0','2022-06-19 13:40:00.0','2022-06-19 13:41:00.0','2022-06-19 13:42:00.0','2022-06-19 13:43:00.0','2022-06-19 13:44:00.0','2022-06-19 13:45:00.0','2022-06-19 13:46:00.0','2022-06-19 13:47:00.0','2022-06-19 13:48:00.0','2022-06-19 13:49:00.0','2022-06-19 13:50:00.0','2022-06-19 13:51:00.0','2022-06-19 13:52:00.0','2022-06-19 13:53:00.0','2022-06-19 13:54:00.0','2022-06-19 13:55:00.0','2022-06-19 13:56:00.0','2022-06-19 13:57:00.0','2022-06-19 13:58:00.0','2022-06-19 13:59:00.0','2022-06-19 14:00:00.0','2022-06-19 14:01:00.0','2022-06-19 14:02:00.0','2022-06-19 14:03:00.0','2022-06-19 14:04:00.0','2022-06-19 14:05:00.0','2022-06-19 14:06:00.0','2022-06-19 14:07:00.0','2022-06-19 14:08:00.0','2022-06-19 14:09:00.0','2022-06-19 14:10:00.0','2022-06-19 14:11:00.0','2022-06-19 14:12:00.0','2022-06-19 14:13:00.0','2022-06-19 14:14:00.0','2022-06-19 14:15:00.0','2022-06-19 14:16:00.0','2022-06-19 14:17:00.0','2022-06-19 14:18:00.0','2022-06-19 14:19:00.0','2022-06-19 14:20:00.0','2022-06-19 14:21:00.0','2022-06-19 14:22:00.0','2022-06-19 14:23:00.0','2022-06-19 14:24:00.0','2022-06-19 14:25:00.0','2022-06-19 14:26:00.0','2022-06-19 14:27:00.0','2022-06-19 14:28:00.0','2022-06-19 14:29:00.0','2022-06-19 14:30:00.0','2022-06-19 14:31:00.0','2022-06-19 14:32:00.0','2022-06-19 14:33:00.0','2022-06-19 14:34:00.0','2022-06-19 14:35:00.0','2022-06-19 14:36:00.0','2022-06-19 14:37:00.0','2022-06-19 14:38:00.0','2022-06-19 14:39:00.0','2022-06-19 14:40:00.0','2022-06-19 14:41:00.0','2022-06-19 14:42:00.0','2022-06-19 14:43:00.0','2022-06-19 14:44:00.0','2022-06-19 14:45:00.0','2022-06-19 14:46:00.0','2022-06-19 14:47:00.0','2022-06-19 14:48:00.0','2022-06-19 14:49:00.0','2022-06-19 14:50:00.0','2022-06-19 14:51:00.0','2022-06-19 14:52:00.0','2022-06-19 14:53:00.0','2022-06-19 14:54:00.0','2022-06-19 14:55:00.0','2022-06-19 14:56:00.0','2022-06-19 14:57:00.0','2022-06-19 14:58:00.0','2022-06-19 14:59:00.0','2022-06-19 15:00:00.0','2022-06-19 15:01:00.0','2022-06-19 15:02:00.0','2022-06-19 15:03:00.0','2022-06-19 15:04:00.0','2022-06-19 15:05:00.0','2022-06-19 15:06:00.0','2022-06-19 15:07:00.0','2022-06-19 15:08:00.0','2022-06-19 15:09:00.0','2022-06-19 15:10:00.0','2022-06-19 15:11:00.0','2022-06-19 15:12:00.0','2022-06-19 15:13:00.0','2022-06-19 15:14:00.0','2022-06-19 15:15:00.0','2022-06-19 15:16:00.0','2022-06-19 15:17:00.0','2022-06-19 15:18:00.0','2022-06-19 15:19:00.0','2022-06-19 15:20:00.0','2022-06-19 15:21:00.0','2022-06-19 15:22:00.0','2022-06-19 15:23:00.0','2022-06-19 15:24:00.0','2022-06-19 15:25:00.0','2022-06-19 15:26:00.0','2022-06-19 15:27:00.0','2022-06-19 15:28:00.0','2022-06-19 15:29:00.0','2022-06-19 15:30:00.0','2022-06-19 15:31:00.0','2022-06-19 15:32:00.0','2022-06-19 15:33:00.0','2022-06-19 15:34:00.0','2022-06-19 15:35:00.0','2022-06-19 15:36:00.0','2022-06-19 15:37:00.0','2022-06-19 15:38:00.0','2022-06-19 15:39:00.0','2022-06-19 15:40:00.0','2022-06-19 15:41:00.0','2022-06-19 15:42:00.0','2022-06-19 15:43:00.0','2022-06-19 15:44:00.0','2022-06-19 15:45:00.0','2022-06-19 15:46:00.0','2022-06-19 15:47:00.0','2022-06-19 15:48:00.0','2022-06-19 15:49:00.0','2022-06-19 15:50:00.0','2022-06-19 15:51:00.0','2022-06-19 15:52:00.0','2022-06-19 15:53:00.0','2022-06-19 15:54:00.0','2022-06-19 15:55:00.0','2022-06-19 15:56:00.0','2022-06-19 15:57:00.0','2022-06-19 15:58:00.0','2022-06-19 15:59:00.0','2022-06-19 16:00:00.0','2022-06-19 16:01:00.0','2022-06-19 16:02:00.0','2022-06-19 16:03:00.0','2022-06-19 16:04:00.0','2022-06-19 16:05:00.0','2022-06-19 16:06:00.0','2022-06-19 16:07:00.0','2022-06-19 16:08:00.0','2022-06-19 16:09:00.0','2022-06-19 16:10:00.0','2022-06-19 16:11:00.0','2022-06-19 16:12:00.0','2022-06-19 16:13:00.0','2022-06-19 16:14:00.0','2022-06-19 16:15:00.0','2022-06-19 16:16:00.0','2022-06-19 16:17:00.0','2022-06-19 16:18:00.0','2022-06-19 16:19:00.0','2022-06-19 16:20:00.0','2022-06-19 16:21:00.0','2022-06-19 16:22:00.0','2022-06-19 16:23:00.0','2022-06-19 16:24:00.0','2022-06-19 16:25:00.0','2022-06-19 16:26:00.0','2022-06-19 16:27:00.0','2022-06-19 16:28:00.0','2022-06-19 16:29:00.0','2022-06-19 16:30:00.0','2022-06-19 16:31:00.0','2022-06-19 16:32:00.0','2022-06-19 16:33:00.0','2022-06-19 16:34:00.0','2022-06-19 16:35:00.0','2022-06-19 16:36:00.0','2022-06-19 16:37:00.0','2022-06-19 16:38:00.0','2022-06-19 16:39:00.0','2022-06-19 16:40:00.0','2022-06-19 16:41:00.0','2022-06-19 16:42:00.0','2022-06-19 16:43:00.0','2022-06-19 16:44:00.0','2022-06-19 16:45:00.0','2022-06-19 16:46:00.0','2022-06-19 16:47:00.0','2022-06-19 16:48:00.0','2022-06-19 16:49:00.0','2022-06-19 16:50:00.0','2022-06-19 16:51:00.0','2022-06-19 16:52:00.0','2022-06-19 16:53:00.0','2022-06-19 16:54:00.0','2022-06-19 16:55:00.0','2022-06-19 16:56:00.0','2022-06-19 16:57:00.0','2022-06-19 16:58:00.0','2022-06-19 16:59:00.0','2022-06-19 17:00:00.0','2022-06-19 17:01:00.0','2022-06-19 17:02:00.0','2022-06-19 17:03:00.0','2022-06-19 17:04:00.0','2022-06-19 17:05:00.0','2022-06-19 17:06:00.0','2022-06-19 17:07:00.0','2022-06-19 17:08:00.0','2022-06-19 17:09:00.0','2022-06-19 17:10:00.0','2022-06-19 17:11:00.0','2022-06-19 17:12:00.0','2022-06-19 17:13:00.0','2022-06-19 17:14:00.0','2022-06-19 17:15:00.0','2022-06-19 17:16:00.0','2022-06-19 17:17:00.0','2022-06-19 17:18:00.0','2022-06-19 17:19:00.0','2022-06-19 17:20:00.0','2022-06-19 17:21:00.0','2022-06-19 17:22:00.0','2022-06-19 17:23:00.0','2022-06-19 17:24:00.0','2022-06-19 17:25:00.0','2022-06-19 17:26:00.0','2022-06-19 17:27:00.0','2022-06-19 17:28:00.0','2022-06-19 17:29:00.0','2022-06-19 17:30:00.0','2022-06-19 17:31:00.0','2022-06-19 17:32:00.0','2022-06-19 17:33:00.0','2022-06-19 17:34:00.0','2022-06-19 17:35:00.0','2022-06-19 17:36:00.0','2022-06-19 17:37:00.0','2022-06-19 17:38:00.0','2022-06-19 17:39:00.0','2022-06-19 17:40:00.0','2022-06-19 17:41:00.0','2022-06-19 17:42:00.0','2022-06-19 17:43:00.0','2022-06-19 17:44:00.0','2022-06-19 17:45:00.0','2022-06-19 17:46:00.0','2022-06-19 17:47:00.0','2022-06-19 17:48:00.0','2022-06-19 17:49:00.0','2022-06-19 17:50:00.0','2022-06-19 17:51:00.0','2022-06-19 17:52:00.0','2022-06-19 17:53:00.0','2022-06-19 17:54:00.0','2022-06-19 17:55:00.0','2022-06-19 17:56:00.0','2022-06-19 17:57:00.0','2022-06-19 17:58:00.0','2022-06-19 17:59:00.0','2022-06-19 18:00:00.0','2022-06-19 18:01:00.0','2022-06-19 18:02:00.0','2022-06-19 18:03:00.0','2022-06-19 18:04:00.0','2022-06-19 18:05:00.0','2022-06-19 18:06:00.0','2022-06-19 18:07:00.0','2022-06-19 18:08:00.0','2022-06-19 18:09:00.0','2022-06-19 18:10:00.0','2022-06-19 18:11:00.0','2022-06-19 18:12:00.0','2022-06-19 18:13:00.0','2022-06-19 18:14:00.0','2022-06-19 18:15:00.0','2022-06-19 18:16:00.0','2022-06-19 18:17:00.0','2022-06-19 18:18:00.0','2022-06-19 18:19:00.0','2022-06-19 18:20:00.0','2022-06-19 18:21:00.0','2022-06-19 18:22:00.0','2022-06-19 18:23:00.0','2022-06-19 18:24:00.0','2022-06-19 18:25:00.0','2022-06-19 18:26:00.0','2022-06-19 18:27:00.0','2022-06-19 18:28:00.0','2022-06-19 18:29:00.0','2022-06-19 18:30:00.0','2022-06-19 18:31:00.0','2022-06-19 18:32:00.0','2022-06-19 18:33:00.0','2022-06-19 18:34:00.0','2022-06-19 18:35:00.0','2022-06-19 18:36:00.0','2022-06-19 18:37:00.0','2022-06-19 18:38:00.0','2022-06-19 18:39:00.0','2022-06-19 18:40:00.0','2022-06-19 18:41:00.0','2022-06-19 18:42:00.0','2022-06-19 18:43:00.0','2022-06-19 18:44:00.0','2022-06-19 18:45:00.0','2022-06-19 18:46:00.0','2022-06-19 18:47:00.0','2022-06-19 18:48:00.0','2022-06-19 18:49:00.0','2022-06-19 18:50:00.0','2022-06-19 18:51:00.0','2022-06-19 18:52:00.0','2022-06-19 18:53:00.0','2022-06-19 18:54:00.0','2022-06-19 18:55:00.0','2022-06-19 18:56:00.0','2022-06-19 18:57:00.0','2022-06-19 18:58:00.0','2022-06-19 18:59:00.0','2022-06-19 19:00:00.0','2022-06-19 19:01:00.0','2022-06-19 19:02:00.0','2022-06-19 19:03:00.0','2022-06-19 19:04:00.0','2022-06-19 19:05:00.0','2022-06-19 19:06:00.0','2022-06-19 19:07:00.0','2022-06-19 19:08:00.0','2022-06-19 19:09:00.0','2022-06-19 19:10:00.0','2022-06-19 19:11:00.0','2022-06-19 19:12:00.0','2022-06-19 19:13:00.0','2022-06-19 19:14:00.0','2022-06-19 19:15:00.0','2022-06-19 19:16:00.0','2022-06-19 19:17:00.0','2022-06-19 19:18:00.0','2022-06-19 19:19:00.0','2022-06-19 19:20:00.0','2022-06-19 19:21:00.0','2022-06-19 19:22:00.0','2022-06-19 19:23:00.0','2022-06-19 19:24:00.0','2022-06-19 19:25:00.0','2022-06-19 19:26:00.0','2022-06-19 19:27:00.0','2022-06-19 19:28:00.0','2022-06-19 19:29:00.0','2022-06-19 19:30:00.0','2022-06-19 19:31:00.0','2022-06-19 19:32:00.0','2022-06-19 19:33:00.0','2022-06-19 19:34:00.0','2022-06-19 19:35:00.0','2022-06-19 19:36:00.0','2022-06-19 19:37:00.0','2022-06-19 19:38:00.0','2022-06-19 19:39:00.0','2022-06-19 19:40:00.0','2022-06-19 19:41:00.0','2022-06-19 19:42:00.0','2022-06-19 19:43:00.0','2022-06-19 19:44:00.0','2022-06-19 19:45:00.0','2022-06-19 19:46:00.0','2022-06-19 19:47:00.0','2022-06-19 19:48:00.0','2022-06-19 19:49:00.0','2022-06-19 19:50:00.0','2022-06-19 19:51:00.0','2022-06-19 19:52:00.0','2022-06-19 19:53:00.0','2022-06-19 19:54:00.0','2022-06-19 19:55:00.0','2022-06-19 19:56:00.0','2022-06-19 19:57:00.0','2022-06-19 19:58:00.0','2022-06-19 19:59:00.0','2022-06-19 20:00:00.0','2022-06-19 20:01:00.0','2022-06-19 20:02:00.0','2022-06-19 20:03:00.0','2022-06-19 20:04:00.0','2022-06-19 20:05:00.0','2022-06-19 20:06:00.0','2022-06-19 20:07:00.0','2022-06-19 20:08:00.0','2022-06-19 20:09:00.0','2022-06-19 20:10:00.0','2022-06-19 20:11:00.0','2022-06-19 20:12:00.0','2022-06-19 20:13:00.0','2022-06-19 20:14:00.0','2022-06-19 20:15:00.0','2022-06-19 20:16:00.0','2022-06-19 20:17:00.0','2022-06-19 20:18:00.0','2022-06-19 20:19:00.0','2022-06-19 20:20:00.0','2022-06-19 20:21:00.0','2022-06-19 20:22:00.0','2022-06-19 20:23:00.0','2022-06-19 20:24:00.0','2022-06-19 20:25:00.0','2022-06-19 20:26:00.0','2022-06-19 20:27:00.0','2022-06-19 20:28:00.0','2022-06-19 20:29:00.0','2022-06-19 20:30:00.0','2022-06-19 20:31:00.0','2022-06-19 20:32:00.0','2022-06-19 20:33:00.0','2022-06-19 20:34:00.0','2022-06-19 20:35:00.0','2022-06-19 20:36:00.0','2022-06-19 20:37:00.0','2022-06-19 20:38:00.0','2022-06-19 20:39:00.0','2022-06-19 20:40:00.0','2022-06-19 20:41:00.0','2022-06-19 20:42:00.0','2022-06-19 20:43:00.0','2022-06-19 20:44:00.0','2022-06-19 20:45:00.0','2022-06-19 20:46:00.0','2022-06-19 20:47:00.0','2022-06-19 20:48:00.0','2022-06-19 20:49:00.0','2022-06-19 20:50:00.0','2022-06-19 20:51:00.0','2022-06-19 20:52:00.0','2022-06-19 20:53:00.0','2022-06-19 20:54:00.0','2022-06-19 20:55:00.0','2022-06-19 20:56:00.0','2022-06-19 20:57:00.0','2022-06-19 20:58:00.0','2022-06-19 20:59:00.0','2022-06-19 21:00:00.0','2022-06-19 21:01:00.0','2022-06-19 21:02:00.0','2022-06-19 21:03:00.0','2022-06-19 21:04:00.0','2022-06-19 21:05:00.0','2022-06-19 21:06:00.0','2022-06-19 21:07:00.0','2022-06-19 21:08:00.0','2022-06-19 21:09:00.0','2022-06-19 21:10:00.0','2022-06-19 21:11:00.0','2022-06-19 21:12:00.0','2022-06-19 21:13:00.0','2022-06-19 21:14:00.0','2022-06-19 21:15:00.0','2022-06-19 21:16:00.0','2022-06-19 21:17:00.0','2022-06-19 21:18:00.0','2022-06-19 21:19:00.0','2022-06-19 21:20:00.0','2022-06-19 21:21:00.0','2022-06-19 21:22:00.0','2022-06-19 21:23:00.0','2022-06-19 21:24:00.0','2022-06-19 21:25:00.0','2022-06-19 21:26:00.0','2022-06-19 21:27:00.0','2022-06-19 21:28:00.0','2022-06-19 21:29:00.0','2022-06-19 21:30:00.0','2022-06-19 21:31:00.0','2022-06-19 21:32:00.0','2022-06-19 21:33:00.0','2022-06-19 21:34:00.0','2022-06-19 21:35:00.0','2022-06-19 21:36:00.0','2022-06-19 21:37:00.0','2022-06-19 21:38:00.0','2022-06-19 21:39:00.0','2022-06-19 21:40:00.0','2022-06-19 21:41:00.0','2022-06-19 21:42:00.0','2022-06-19 21:43:00.0','2022-06-19 21:44:00.0','2022-06-19 21:45:00.0','2022-06-19 21:46:00.0','2022-06-19 21:47:00.0','2022-06-19 21:48:00.0','2022-06-19 21:49:00.0','2022-06-19 21:50:00.0','2022-06-19 21:51:00.0','2022-06-19 21:52:00.0','2022-06-19 21:53:00.0','2022-06-19 21:54:00.0','2022-06-19 21:55:00.0','2022-06-19 21:56:00.0','2022-06-19 21:57:00.0','2022-06-19 21:58:00.0','2022-06-19 21:59:00.0','2022-06-19 22:00:00.0','2022-06-19 22:01:00.0','2022-06-19 22:02:00.0','2022-06-19 22:03:00.0','2022-06-19 22:04:00.0','2022-06-19 22:05:00.0','2022-06-19 22:06:00.0','2022-06-19 22:07:00.0','2022-06-19 22:08:00.0','2022-06-19 22:09:00.0','2022-06-19 22:10:00.0','2022-06-19 22:11:00.0','2022-06-19 22:12:00.0','2022-06-19 22:13:00.0','2022-06-19 22:14:00.0','2022-06-19 22:15:00.0','2022-06-19 22:16:00.0','2022-06-19 22:17:00.0','2022-06-19 22:18:00.0','2022-06-19 22:19:00.0','2022-06-19 22:20:00.0','2022-06-19 22:21:00.0','2022-06-19 22:22:00.0','2022-06-19 22:23:00.0','2022-06-19 22:24:00.0','2022-06-19 22:25:00.0','2022-06-19 22:26:00.0','2022-06-19 22:27:00.0','2022-06-19 22:28:00.0','2022-06-19 22:29:00.0','2022-06-19 22:30:00.0','2022-06-19 22:31:00.0','2022-06-19 22:32:00.0','2022-06-19 22:33:00.0','2022-06-19 22:34:00.0','2022-06-19 22:35:00.0','2022-06-19 22:36:00.0','2022-06-19 22:37:00.0','2022-06-19 22:38:00.0','2022-06-19 22:39:00.0','2022-06-19 22:40:00.0','2022-06-19 22:41:00.0','2022-06-19 22:42:00.0','2022-06-19 22:43:00.0','2022-06-19 22:44:00.0','2022-06-19 22:45:00.0','2022-06-19 22:46:00.0','2022-06-19 22:47:00.0','2022-06-19 22:48:00.0','2022-06-19 22:49:00.0','2022-06-19 22:50:00.0','2022-06-19 22:51:00.0','2022-06-19 22:52:00.0','2022-06-19 22:53:00.0','2022-06-19 22:54:00.0','2022-06-19 22:55:00.0','2022-06-19 22:56:00.0','2022-06-19 22:57:00.0','2022-06-19 22:58:00.0','2022-06-19 22:59:00.0','2022-06-19 23:00:00.0','2022-06-19 23:01:00.0','2022-06-19 23:02:00.0','2022-06-19 23:03:00.0','2022-06-19 23:04:00.0','2022-06-19 23:05:00.0','2022-06-19 23:06:00.0','2022-06-19 23:07:00.0','2022-06-19 23:08:00.0','2022-06-19 23:09:00.0','2022-06-19 23:10:00.0','2022-06-19 23:11:00.0','2022-06-19 23:12:00.0','2022-06-19 23:13:00.0','2022-06-19 23:14:00.0','2022-06-19 23:15:00.0','2022-06-19 23:16:00.0','2022-06-19 23:17:00.0','2022-06-19 23:18:00.0','2022-06-19 23:19:00.0','2022-06-19 23:20:00.0','2022-06-19 23:21:00.0','2022-06-19 23:22:00.0','2022-06-19 23:23:00.')
```

I can understand saying there is a issue with the quotations, but I cant find it anywhere. It seems as there is a maximum allowed in a vector, if I compile only the first quarter of the entries it works, else wise on R studio it gives an error, and in the terminal it just expects more code so it gives you a + to add more instead of >.

Comment: the issue might be unmatched quote. Ensure that all the quotes are matched

Comment: ALWAYS include complete error messages. And if you "process" two atomic vectors with `c` then you get 1 atomic vector. If they were of dissimilar types then they are coerced to be the lowest common denominator type according to the loose typing features of R's type system.

Comment: The included error message ends with a non-quote character, so it's "incomplete" and appears to confirm the guess of @onyambu Since the error message is a bit opaque, we now need to see the code that created it.

Comment: Your error cannot be reproduced. The `dt` you provided runs fine

Comment: Are you saying it runs fine in your code? It gives me an error every time I try running it in R studio